# Adapting to the disappearance of the IMDb datasets

Tags: amazon-s3, dataset, imdb

So the freely available [IMDb datasets](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces) will disappear at the end of 2017.

From what I understand, you must:

- identify yourself (register a personal account for all access)
- pay money (once a free quota is used up, though the actual price may be minuscule)
- write code (though it looks like you're downloading .gz files, so probably simple)

Some questions arise from this:

1. What does the data format look like? There's a brief example on the page, but does anyone have an actual file showing how titles, years, votes, etc. are formatted and linked?
2. What are your options if you don't want to go along with this regime? Are there freely available copies of the datasets somewhere? What other freely available film databases exist that at least cover all movies and TV series with a minimum of interest released since 2017 onward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Talking about the paywall**

The new files amount to about 360 megabytes of data, so from what I understand of the S3 pricing, you will be well inside the free cap unless you'll download it many times a month.

**What does the data format look like?**

They seem to be dumps of database tables.

As an example, here it is the beginning of title.basics.tsv.gz:

```
tconst  titleType       primaryTitle    originalTitle   isAdult startYear       endYear runtimeMinutes  genres
tt0000001       short   Carmencita      Carmencita      0       1894    \N      1       Documentary,Short
tt0000002       short   Le clown et ses chiens  Le clown et ses chiens  0       1892    \N      5       Animation,Short
tt0000003       short   Pauvre Pierrot  Pauvre Pierrot  0       1892    \N      4       Animation,Comedy,Romance
tt0000004       short   Un bon bock     Un bon bock     0       1892    \N      \N      Animation,Short
```

The available files are: title.basics.tsv.gz, title.crew.tsv.gz, title.episode.tsv.gz, title.principals.tsv.gz, title.ratings.tsv.gz and name.basics.tsv.gz

In terms of contained data, those are the fields in each file:

```
name.basics.tsv.gz
nconst primaryName birthYear deathYear primaryProfession knownForTitles

title.basics.tsv.gz
tconst titleType primaryTitle originalTitle isAdult startYear endYear runtimeMinutes genres

title.crew.tsv.gz
tconst directors writers

title.episode.tsv.gz
tconst parentTconst seasonNumber episodeNumber

title.principals.tsv.gz
tconst principalCast

title.ratings.tsv.gz
tconst averageRating numVotes
```

Talking about number of lines in each file, we currently (2017-080-21) have:

```
name.basics.tsv.gz 8086560
title.basics.tsv.gz 4466246
title.crew.tsv.gz 4466246
title.episode.tsv.gz 2934335
title.principals.tsv.gz 3957899
title.ratings.tsv.gz 757412
```

**What are your options if you don't want to go along with this regime?**

Not many, I fear.
But if the price is the only concern, see above.

All of my findings about the new format are in [this thread on the imdbpy-devel mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/imdbpy/mailman/message/35922484/)

**What other freely available film databases exist**

I think the best alternative are https://www.themoviedb.org/ and http://www.omdbapi.com/ but I'm not too familiar with neither.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! 1. Is the download quota periodical or a one time thing (I thought the latter)? 2. Does the new data contain: Language, Running time, Production Company and Distribution Company? (Where Language is the *primary* language that appears first in the old lists.) Could you  share the top of all the files, since they are few and a lot of information like actors, directors, etc. seems to be missing. 3. Will the IMDBpy framework be changed in time for the transition so that this is a viable option?

Comment: @forthrin : **1.** from their [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) I desume that the first GB/month is free. **2.** I've updated the answers to show the header of each file and the number of lines. **3.** I hope so, but my time is very limited; Basically, we need developers. :-)

Comment: The new data does NOT contain the Language (or Running Time, etc.) spoken in the film?? This is a complete disaster. Will IMDBpy require the user to have his own account to the new IMDb data sets, or will a (transformed?) copy of the data be available as part of IMDBpy?

Comment: @forthrin yes: no language, no country and many other information are missing (but running time is present: *title.runtimeMinutes*). I have to double-check their license, but probably each user will have to download the data using their own account for legal reasons. PS: if the answer is good for you, please accept it.

Comment: a little update: a well informed source told me that IMDb is planning to add more information to the distributed data set.  That's good, since the the format is much easier to parse.

Comment: That's nice, but I still want to be able to fetch the data anonymously and free. How can I do that?

Comment: @forthrin: that's explicitly forbidden by their terms of service (point 2 of http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?usedatasoftware )

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by grabbing the the old style text files and building a database with IMDBpy, and then updating it from these new files. IMDBpy might already support this.